# View is clipped automatically

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, uistoryboard

[image]

I have a UIView of size 320*178 but it's showing only some part (around 320*120) .
I am unable to figure,how my view is clipped. Have I set any property to YES unknowingly or I'm missing something.

I have drawn the view in storyboard, no code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give more information. Perhaps show some code for how you configure the view, and anything related to its frame on auto layout constraints.

Comment: People will need code snippet to get more idea.

Comment: @0x7fffffff ,  I have dragged the uiview to viewcontroller in my storyboard. Set it size of 320*178.

Comment: And I'm guessing that you added it to a 4 inch screen in interface builder, but you're running it on a 3.5 inch simulator or device? You need to adjust the constraints on the view.

Comment: @0x7fffffff , I've added in 4inch and run on 4inch device.

Comment: Assuming AutoLayout is enabled, try setting width and height constraints on the UIView through the IB and see if the view still gets clipped.

Comment: You are using autolayout or auto-resizing? Post a screenshot.

Comment: Okay, thanks everybody for your valuable suggestions. @VinodVishwanath , now it's fine , thank you.

Comment: @Thapa, you're welcome. Please update with an answer explaining what exactly worked to fix the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I knew it would be some kind of silly mistake that developers usually come across. On running the code, myview was clipping. I was focused on only thing that how can the view be clipped automatically.Finally after going through all the suggestions,I tackled it by setting the background color of myview to redcolor. Then, I found the clipping magic which lost my 2-3 hrs was actually myview's size 45-55 was overlapped by the unknown view from the code.